# How to take results of a function and apply it to function again in R?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am aware this is a very basic question and am sorry to take up everyone's time. I created a function but would like to take those results, and apply it to the function again ( I am trying to model growth).

I don't think I want to use a loop because I need the values to come from the function. I also don't think it's apply because I need to extract the values from the function.

Here is my function

```
initial<-c(36.49)
second<-NULL

growth <- function(x){
 second <- (131.35-(131.35 -x)*exp(-0.087))
 }
second<-growth(initial)
third<-growth(second)
fourth<-growth(third)
fifth<-growth(fourth)
sixth<-growth(fifth)
seventh<-growth(sixth)
```

here is how I am doing it now, but as you can see I would have to keep doing this over and over again

Comment: thank you so much! Now I can model for 100 + years in seconds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loop. Just store the outputs in a vector:

```
# initial value
initial<-c(36.49)

# dont need this i think
# second<-NULL

# create a holding vector fro result
values <- vector()

# assign
values[1] <- initial

# your function
growth <- function(x){
  second <- (131.35-(131.35 -x)*exp(-0.087))
}

# start a loop; you start with 2
for(i in 2:7){

    # then access the previous value using i - 1
    # then store to the next index, which is i
    values[i] <-  growth(values[i - 1])
}
```

This should do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this maybe can help

```
x <- 1
try <- function(x) x <<- x+1
for(i in 1:5) try(x)
```